# Firefox not loading css for radio buttons

Tags: html, css, firefox

so i have this html code for radio buttons which works perfect on chrome but the css for radio buttons on firefox isnt working. What could be the problem?that is the code i have,is there anything im missing?

```css
input[type='radio'] {
 
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin: 25% auto;    
    border-radius:50%;    
}
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background-color: #0496fd;
}

.bob-bound
{   
    padding-bottom:0.2px;
 padding-right:10px;
 margin:auto;
 border: solid 0px blue;
 height: 110px;
 position:relative;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.bob-bound-type-lable{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:30px;
 border: solid 0px red;
 width: 239px;
    height: 18px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
}

.bob-button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 46px;
    vertical-align:right;
    background-color: #ffffff ;
    border: solid 1px #bfbfbf;
    padding-left:5px;
    font-family: ArialMT, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left:12px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.bob-button:hover {
 background-color: #f3f8fd;
}


.bob-recommendation-button
{   
    position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 width: 292px;
 top:49px; 
 border: solid 0px red;
}

.bob-Inbound{
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    margin-left:8px;
    width: 112px;
    height: 17px;
    font-family: ArialMT, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: solid 0px red;
}

.bob-Outbound {
 position:absolute;
 top:6px;
 margin-left:12px;
    width: 239px;
    height: 17px;
    font-family: ArialMT, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: solid 0px red;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.bob-bound-type{
 position: absolute;
 width:437px;
 margin-top:56px;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-left:27px;
 border: solid 0px red;
}
.bob-radio{
    background:green;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
}

.bob-second-radio{
 margin-left:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bob-bound">
    <div class="bob-bound-type-lable">
        Contact Type
    </div>

    <div class="bob-bound-type">
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="Inbound" class="bob-radio" value="Inbound" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="Inbound" class="bob-Inbound">Inbound</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="Outbound" class="bob-radio bob-second-radio" value="Outbound"/>
        <label for="Outbound" class="bob-Outbound">Outbound</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the way its supposed to display:

[image]

Comment: input element doesn't support pseudo-elements : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general consensus is that styling radio buttons in Firefox with CSS is a fool's errand.  But there are several workarounds that achieve the same effect.  My personal favorite is to hide the actual radio button and instead use images to show if it is checked or unchecked.

There's a nice working example here:

[Mozilla Firefox input radio button styling and default settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081748/mozilla-firefox-input-radio-button-styling-and-default-settings)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, the solution works perfect @az0

Answer (score 1):

Styling input elements (in particular radio buttons and checkboxes) can be unreliable across navigators. You're better off applying the styling to the label or a pseudo element.